# Allow commenting on deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-answers

Sometimes I'd like to comment on deleted answers, for example to say that the answer's idea is actually good and how the issue that led to its deletion can be fixed.

Comment: @rene I'm not familiar with reviews. I meant answers deleted by their authors. It's rare, but often enough that it has bothered me enough to ask for this. What kind of abuse? I can see these answers because I have 10k+ reputation, can we maybe act like I know what I'm doing and how to behave? Did you mean "likely" instead of "unlikely"? The author of the answer is who I want it to see (they should get notified as usual), so they can fix the issue, undelete, and thus we'd have a valuable answer.

Comment: Sometimes people delete their answer because they believe they've made a mistake and want to move past it. They'll either edit and undelete it or just move on.

Comment: @JonClements Hmm, I can't tell whether you're for or against this :-). My point for this use case is that they're not aware that there's a fix for their mistake and they won't fix it unless they're made aware of it. I also might've had other use cases, but the last two I remember we're like this. And unlike rene, I don't see a downside in this.

Comment: This has bothered me a few times in the past too and it would be a nice-to-have feature. Having said that, I don't think there's enough demand for it or that many users will stand behind it, therefore, it's unlikely to be implemented. BTW, I don't really think abuse is an issue here. The author of the answer would be notified of the comment and they can flag it if it's flag-worthy. Anyone else who can see the comment also has the ability to flag it. @rene, what kind of abuse are you worried about?

Comment: i can't see the benifit, for ame reason the answer is deleted, and if you want make your own answer.

Answer (score 13):

No, let's not allow that.

If answers are deleted from review the comments posted by the community bot are still there.

What type of answers would benefit from this then?
Are we really deleting that many answers that could be salvaged if we left guidance in comments?
Are there really that many self-deleted answers that need salvaging by means of comments?

If you really can salvage a deleted answer, post it yourself, preferable as community wiki, with credits to the OP of the deleted answer. In case the OP circles back and finds your answer and they decide to edit their original and undelete, you can delete your CW again. Problem solved. We don't need a comment feature for that.

On a tangential note: these comments would be extremely hard, if not impossible to moderate by regular users. I can see this being abused on so many levels (think stalking, pressuring users to undelete, continued arguing after a "bad" answer was given, etc. Do you want more examples? Ask a mod to read back for us their latest custom comment flags and/or rude/abusive flags) . Let's not clutter the site with comments, specially on places where it is likely only the OP or a casual passerby will notice them, if at all.

Comment: @KellyBundy because sometimes someone just didn't like their answer or will work on it later (or not). Or maybe just has one of those "oh gawd, I wish I'd not posted that - so embarassing moments"

Comment: Regarding stalking/pressuring/etc: flag it then.

Comment: @KellyBundy if you find anything at all that breaches the code of conduct for this site - then flag it.

Comment: @JonClements Sure, maybe for some reason they'd not want to fix/undelete. And then they could ignore the comment (or respond if they feel like it).

Comment: @KellyBundy errr... but why should they get comments on it - they're either working on it or moved away from it... you just don't know as someone possibly on the other side of the planet we live on which one it is... maybe if I've made a bad answer (and darn sure I'm made several) - I want to put my paws up and say "yeah - that was my stupid mis-interpreting of the question"... I certainly wouldn't like people to then be able to comment on that answer with stuff like "oh yeah - that was stupid!" or something

Comment: @JonClements About flagging: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Simply flag it just like you'd flag under non-deleted posts. And like I pointed out, only people with 10k+ reputation can even *see* deleted answers. And my guess is that such users are far less "abusive" than the average user, so I'd also expect abuse under deleted answers to be far rarer because of that.

Comment: @JonClements You really think people with 10k+ reputation would write "oh yeah - that was stupid!"? And even if they did, simply flag.

Comment: @KellyBundy reputation doesn't affect how you behave... there's plenty of really good developers out there that have next to zero interpersonal skills at all. (So yes, there's 10k or 50k+ users I'd feel uncomfortable being able to do this)

Comment: @JonClements Those same people and more can also post abuse under non-deleted posts. So... Let's remove the possibility for comments altogether?

Comment: However, those posts and comments can be moderated by the community in large @KellyBundy.  Just FLAG! :)

Comment: @JonClements Just like under deleted ones, no? What's the difference?

Comment: @KellyBundy maybe I've not had enough coffee this morning... but I thought it was clear by now what the difference is? Anyway, I have to do that "real life" thing so I'm going to leave this for now. And errr, let rene not get so many notifications...